# Cannot read property 'on' of null

Tags: jquery, magento

I'm trying to get a bit of jQuery working for a ripple effect when you click the button.

Right now it pulls jquery in the document head, and then after the button there is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
(function(){

$(".solar-button").on("click", function(e){

    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var clickY = y - $(this).offset().top;
    var clickX = x - $(this).offset().left;
var box = this;

var setX = parseInt(clickX);
var setY = parseInt(clickY);
$(this).find("svg").remove();
$(this).append('<svg><circle cx="'+setX+'" cy="'+setY+'" r="'+0+'"></circle></svg>');

setTimeout(function(){
  var c = $(box).find("circle");
  c.animate(
    {
      "r" : $(box).outerWidth()
    },
    {
      easing: "easeOutQuad",
      duration: 500,
        step : function(val){
                    c.attr("r", val);
                }
    }
  );

});

});

}());
```

For some reason I'm getting the error

> "cannot read property 'on' of null".

If I put jQuery right above the call for jquery easing then it works... however then my sites menu doesn't work since jQuery is also called in the head. Not sure why it's not able to use the same jQuery in the head of my document.

The link I'm currently trying this on is [here](http://bftgateopeners.com/store/information/ecosol-solar-powered-system.html) for the button at the bottom. Having no luck. I'd try this in a fiddle but putting everything that could be conflicting with jQuery in a Magento site is insane.

Comment: for starters, change where you have (function(){ to be $(function() {

Answer (score 2):

What is most likely happening is you are trying to access an element that jQuery doesn't know exists because of the positioning of your function.

Instead, try :

```
$(document).on("click", ".solar-button", function(e){
   //my function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript tends to execute as soon as it occurrs. You mention that this doesn't work in the  block, which makes sense because none of the body has been loaded yet. There are two options for this:

1. Include your javascript at the bottom of the page. I've seen this done, but don't know if this is exactly best practice or not.
2. Probably your best solution is to use [jQuery(callback)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3). This specifically executes any functions you pass after the DOM has fully loaded.

Hope this helps, and best of luck!